# Clear contents of text file FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

Typically I'd use `> /var/log/snort/alert` however on FreeBSD this doesn't work. 'Invalid null command' error is thrown. Any way to do this other than deleting and making a new file?

Comment: You could use `truncate`

Comment: clarify your question with the full command used and how you did that, because `> /var/log/snort/alert` does nothing at all.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work canonically on all Unix-like systems: `echo > /path/to/file`. Most important is that the file descriptor will be retained.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```bash
shell> cat /dev/null > /var/log/snort/alert
```